# TypeError: in txt to list discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i want to make a bot that say bruh when your mesage is equal to the word in bruh.txt

my code:

```
bruh_file = open("bruh.txt", "r")
bruh_mo = [(line.strip()).split() for line in bruh_file]
bruh_file.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo):
    await message.channel.send("bruh")
```

but when i try it , it did'nt responed and i get this:

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 53, in on_message
> if any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo):
> File "main.py", line 53, in 
> if any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo):
> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list
> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 53, in on_message
> if any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo):
> File "main.py", line 53, in 
> if any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo):
> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list
> 172.18.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2021 09:27:25] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `bruh_mo = [(line.strip()).split() for line in bruh_file]` makes `bruh_mo` a list of lists, so when you do `any(word in msg for word in bruh_mo)` you're basically checking if a list (i.e. `word`) exists in a string (i.e. `msg`). Hence the error `TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list`.